# PHP Form: After getting results adding a new table row when entering new information

Tags: php

Although probarly quite simple, i cannot seem to find the following.
The form takes certain data, and then represents the data in a table.

Next step i click the hyperlink that takes me back to the form.
Now my question is how exactly do i make it possible when filling in the same form again so both results are displayed in the same table?
Then filling in a other form with data adds another row and so on.

Regards.

The code below (pardon me that it is not english).

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0            Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>ExpoFormulier</title>
```

```
<body>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
$standnaam = $_POST["standnaam"];
$oppervlakte = $_POST["oppervlakte"];
//value in the form van checkboxes op 1 zetten!
$verdieping = isset($_POST["verdieping"]) ? $_POST["verdieping"] : 0;  //if checkbox    checked value 1 anders 0
$telefoon = isset($_POST["telefoon"]) ? $_POST["telefoon"] : 0;  
$netwerk = isset($_POST["netwerk"]) ? $_POST["netwerk"] : 0; 


if (is_numeric($oppervlakte)) 
{
    $_SESSION["standnaam"]=$standnaam;
    $_SESSION["oppervlakte"]=$oppervlakte;
    $_SESSION["verdieping"]=$verdieping;
    $_SESSION["telefoon"]=$telefoon;
    $_SESSION["netwerk"]=$netwerk;
    header("Location:ExpoOverzicht.php"); //verzenden naar ExpoOverzicht.php dmv header
}
else 
{
    echo "<h1>Foute gegevens, Opnieuw invullen a.u.b</h1>";
}  
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="form1">
<h1>Vul de gegevens in</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Standnaam:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="standnaam" size="18"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oppervlakte (in m^2):</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oppervlakte" size="6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Verdieping:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="verdieping" value="1"/></td>
        <!--value op 1 zetten voor checkbox! indien checked is value 1 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefoon:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="telefoon" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Netwerk:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="netwerk" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verzenden"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Second File:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ExpoOverzicht</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="StyleSheetExpo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>

<body>

<h1>Overzicht van de ingegeven standen in deze sessie</h1>

<?php

$standnaam = $_SESSION["standnaam"];
$oppervlakte = $_SESSION["oppervlakte"];
$verdieping = $_SESSION["verdieping"];
$telefoon = $_SESSION["telefoon"];
$netwerk = $_SESSION["netwerk"];

$result1 = 0; //telkens declaren anders fout "undefined variable"
$result2 = 0;
$result3 = 0;
$prijsCom = 0;
$prijsVerdieping = 0;

for ($i=1; $i <= $oppervlakte; $i++)
{   
    if($i <= 10)
    {
       $tarief1 = 1 * 100;
       $result1 += $tarief1;
    }

    if($i > 10 && $i <= 30)
    {
        $tarief2 = 1 * 90;
        $result2 += $tarief2;      
    }

    if($i > 30)
    {
        $tarief3 = 1 * 80;
        $result3 += $tarief3;
    }  
}
$prijsOpp = $result1 + $result2 + $result3;


if($verdieping == 1)
{
    $prijsVerdieping = $oppervlakte * 120;
}


if(($telefoon == 1) || ($netwerk == 1)) // eerst deze OR conditie  of anders gebruikt de code alleen nog maar 20
{
    $prijsCom = 20;
}

if(($telefoon == 1) && ($netwerk == 1))
{
    $prijsCom = 30;
}


$totalePrijs = $prijsOpp + $prijsVerdieping + $prijsCom; 

echo "<table class=\"tableExpo\">";

    echo "<th>Standnaam</th>";
    echo "<th>Oppervlakte</th>";
    echo "<th>Verdieping</th>";
    echo "<th>Telefoon</th>";
    echo "<th>Netwerk</th>";
    echo "<th>Totale prijs</th>";

        echo "<tr>";     
            echo "<td>".$standnaam."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$oppervlakte."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$verdieping."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$telefoon."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$netwerk."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$totalePrijs."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

?>

<a href="ExpoFormulier.php">Terug naar het formulier</a>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session variables will only store the last piece of data entered.  Rather than storing them in the session as simple variables, try putting an array in the session.  Then when the form is submitted again, add another entry to those arrays.  That way you won't overwrite what was previously there.

ETA:

On Page 1, where you set the session variables, try this:

```
$_SESSION["standnaam"][]=$standnaam;
$_SESSION["oppervlakte"][]=$oppervlakte;
$_SESSION["verdieping"][]=$verdieping;
$_SESSION["telefoon"][]=$telefoon;
$_SESSION["netwerk"][]=$netwerk;
```

On Page 2, where you write out the table rows, try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($standnaam); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";     
        echo "<td>".$standnaam[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$oppervlakte[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$verdieping[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$telefoon[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$netwerk[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$totalePrijs[$i]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I think that aught to do it.

Comment: Hello, could you care to explain a bit more? Cause arrays are quite confusing me in php.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Although what is the syntax of [] behind that? Getting loads of errors while doing that. Should i make $... = array(....) somewhere? I keep getting 6x the same data in the table.  How can i let php know i am using a form again for a second wave of input? Kind Regards.

Comment: @Chris - the [] syntax says "add another element to the end of this array".  It might not be working because the element isn't initialized as an array.  You might need to initialize it first, like this: `if (!isset($_session["standnaam"]) $_SESSION["standnaam"] = array()`